# web element not found with appium

Tags: appium

I am new Appium I have run a sample code of google and test it with appium and for google its working fine and testing the google site with tag name, So I start testing the URL with tag names but the URL which  I am testing doesn't have any tag name it only has xpaths and ids. Now my problem is I tried with xpath like this   WebElement enterLogin = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@name='_NNext']")); but its not working its simple through exception and said that element is not found.

Please some one help me I am stuck here and its almost a week that I trying it and searching for the sloutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add this thing in the capabilities.setCapability("automationName", "selendroid"); and it will work fine –